# How to set default doctype in Gulp-Jade

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pug, gulp

I am having a problem with `gulp-jade`: The Jade compiler always adds a value to HTML attributes without a value, which breaks my AngularJS setup. (e.g. `div(ui-view)` becomes `<div ui-view="ui-view">` when I want `<div ui-view>`.

The problem does not occur with files that have a `doctype html`, but since I am mostly working with 'partials' that is no help.

I am running `.pipe(jade())` without additional options. Apparently `gulp-jade` supports all Jade API options, [listed here](http://jade-lang.com/api/), but I do not see which one would apply here.

Comment: This issue is Jade specific and not related with gulp. Same behavior with `grunt-contrib-jade`. I have not find any workaround...

Comment: It seems that way, but there has to be some solution. I have used `brunch` before and it did not have that issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an undocumented `doctype` option. `.pipe(jade({doctype: 'html'}))` compiles the template under the HTML5 doctype

Comment: FYI, it does seem to be documented now on the jade website: http://jade-lang.com/api/

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this page who use Grunt, I found that the following works with ui-view.

```
div(ui-view="")
```